# Jquery animation works for only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

- the function stops images under to fade.
- Now, works for only one element (`div.logo`) which is the second one, how can I make it working for both or many?

I guess I should get the borders of each element in the resulting list. how?

Any help would be much appreciated

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZxwY/

JS:

```
function displayThese(selectorString) {
    var $heading = $(selectorString);
    var h1top = $heading.position().top;
    var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
    var h1left = $heading.position().left;
    var h1right = h1top + $heading.width();

    var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();
        var left = $e.position().left;
        var right = left + $e.width();

        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top || left > h1right || right < h1left;
    });
    return divs;
}

(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divsToChange = displayThese('h1, div.logo');
    var elem = divsToChange.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divsToChange.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    // Get items that do not change    
    var divs = $('li').not(displayThese());
    divs.css({
        opacity: 0.3
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should execute  fadeInDiv() function at the end of document load, because in your fiddle, the positions are calculated as inline (same top and bottom for all 'li').

On the other hand, when getting the position and dimension of a selector, it takes the attributes of the first element. So it won't work on your example. You need to pass only one element.

What you need to do is to iterate through elements matching selectorString, filtering the list of "li" elements that aren't behind of those.

```
function displayThese(selectorString) {
    var divs = $('li');

   // iterate through elements in selector filtering <li> elements
   $(selectorString).each( function( index, value ) {
       var $heading = $(this);
       var h1top = $heading.position().top;
       var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
       var h1left = $heading.position().left;
       var h1right = h1top + $heading.width();   

     divs = divs.filter(function () {
         var $e = $(this);
         var top = $e.position().top;
         var bottom = top + $e.height();
         var left = $e.position().left;
         var right = left + $e.width();

         // return just the elements non touching the selectors
         return !(top < h1bottom && bottom > h1top && 
                 left < h1right && right > h1left);
     });
 });

  return divs;
}
```

at resize you must stop current animations and start fade method again:

```
$(window).resize(function () {    
    $('li').stop();
    $('li').css("opacity", "0.3");
    fadeInDiv();    
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXhnp/8/) of this

Comment: thank you so much! it should work on the opposite way. So images are fading in and out, but the one on under the elements shouldn't fade

Comment: also the animation function is not longer there

Comment: I need the images to keep fading in and out! could u help?

Comment: any chance you can have a look the resize function too? shall I execute the fadeInDiv(); in there? it seems to spee all up?

Comment: great work btw, Just need to see if on resize works too

Comment: resize is easiest part. Just stop all current animations, set the opacity to 0.3 again and start fade method: